# insert a row and a line in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I create a matrix `b` from a matrix `a` in the following way:

```
a=[1 2 ; 3 4];

b= [a zeros(2); zeros(2) a]

b =

     1     2     0     0
     3     4     0     0
     0     0     1     2
     0     0     3     4
```

Successively, I want to insert a line and a column of zeros at a certain point of the matrix. Let's say at middle way:

```
idx=2;
c=[b(1:idx,:); zeros(1,4); b(idx+1:end,:)]
c =

     1     2     0     0
     3     4     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     2
     0     0     3     4

c=[c(:,1:idx) zeros(5,1) c(:,idx+1:end)]

c =

     1     2     0     0     0
     3     4     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     2
     0     0     0     3     4
```

Is there a more intelligent way of doing this?

Comment: on basic improvement is to use `size(b, 2)` and `size(c, 1)` instead of hard-coding 4 and 5 in the zeros call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way(I don't know if it is a more intelligent way).

Assuming that you have the row index as `row` and the column index as `col`:

```
sc = size(b) + 1;
c = zeros(sc);
ROW = true(sc(1), 1);
ROW(row) = false;
COL = true(1, sc(2));
COL(col) = false;
```

Then in MATLAB r2016b /Octave you can write

```
c(ROW & COL)=b;
```

In pre 2016b you can use `bsxfun`

```
c(bsxfun(@and, ROW , COL))=b;
```